# How to connet two cylinders

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode

[image: Two Cylinders]

I've tried looking this problem up but haven't found an answer

Comment: Are those two seperate objects? If so, you'll have to join them (Ctrl-J) in Object mode. You can then use the Loop Tools addon to join them in Edit mode.